# How to set django admin panel not to load css from aws s3 but from default?

Tags: python-3.x, django, amazon-s3

In my django project i am using amazon s3 to store files (media, css, js). The site is loading properly but django admin panel does not, it is in plain html. How do I make it work properly, what should I add or change in my settings?

S3 configuration:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '***'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '***'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = '***'

AWS_S3_HOST = 's3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME="eu-central-1"

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'`   and `manage.py collectstatic` solved the issue